# I have a question about transfer data from user to another

Tags: php, mysql, function

Right now, I have a small problem. I need to make input to send coins from user to another user, so how  can I get the sender ID and the receiver ID from database, and when the transfer is done, the coins should deducted from sender.

I've tried many ways to make it work but it didn't.

```
// my input
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="coins_send" class="control-label"></label> 
          <input id="coins_send"  type="number" class="form-control">
          <input id="receiver_id" type="hidden" class="form-control">
      </div>
<button onclick="SaveCoinsFor()" class="btn btn-primary"></button>

//  Javascript
SaveCoinsFor= function(){
var new_name =  $('#coins_send').val(),target_id=$('#receiver_id').val();
$.post('system/coins_set.php', { 
    token: utk,
    target_id:target_id ,
    coins_send:coins_send,
    action:"send_coins",
    }, function(response) {
        if(response == 1)callSaved(system.saved, 1);
        else callSaved(system.error, 3);
});
}
```

my database columns `user_id` and `coins`
so now I want to set coins_set.php file to make this transfer.

Note: I want to make sure when user coins = 0, he can't transfer any coins.

I know for sure there's something wrong with my codes. Anyway i'm still learning, so maybe someone can help me.

Comment: I assume your sender is logged in, therefore you already know the senders ID within your application. Is that whats you're asking?

Comment: @paskl nope, i'm asking about how i can make a function with a sender ID and receiver ID, and make coins deducted from Sender.

Comment: The only way to get the sender ID is by having a login system of some sort, do you have that?

Comment: @Dmitri Chebotarev actually my system is chat, so yea i have it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is rather simple since you already have a login system.

Here is some psuedo code to help you get started:

```php
<?php
// system/coins_set.php

session_start();

$senderId = $_SESSION['user_id']; // <- depending on how you store the user ofcourse
$targetId = $_POST['target_id']; 
$coinsToSend = $_POST['coins_send']; // We will send 3 coins


// Here you would normally get the balance from the database.
// This will be the total amount of coins the current user has now.
$balance = 4;


// Here we will simply substract the coins we want to send from the total
$newBalance = $balance - $coinsToSend;

// Check if we have enough coins to do this

if ($newBalance < 0) {
    exit('not enough coins');
}

// Update the current users balance
// This will be '1' in our case

// You would do something like this:
// UPDATE users SET coins = $newBalance WHERE user_id = $senderId

// and also update the balance of the target
// Get current coins from targetUser
// SELECT coins FROM users WHERE user_id = $targetId

// let's say the coins is 4
$targetCoins = 4;
$targetCoins += $coinsToSend;

// UPDATE users SET coins = $targetCoins WHERE user_id = $targetId
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually it's helping me, but can you help me with update query to update `coins` column for each user. sender and receiver